# how to change default index.codec for new index?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

How can change index.codec for "best_compression"?
I want to create all new index with this compression type.

I add this: "index.codec: best_compression" to /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
but no effect.

Comment: Can you check your templates to make sure that there is no codec defined at that level?

Comment: where is the templates?

Comment: `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_template`

Comment: thanks. i found it. but i do not know how to change them

Comment: information regarding templates is available at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html you should read it. I tested and using PUT on an exising template overrides the previous values, probably the cleanest approach would be to define a template containing only the index.codec information, with a higher order than the other templates, and matching the indices of interes to you (do note this will only work for new indices, won't modify the existing ones)

Answer (score 0):

index.codec is an index level setting not a cluster level setting that's used for all indexes in a cluster.

You can set it when you create the index:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my-index-1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
     {
        "settings": { 
          "index": { 
            "codec": "best_compression" 
          }
        }
      }'
```